# Search Results Keep Loading

Tags: 2013, cme, search

while searching in Tridion CME, it says "Showing N results, sorted by Best Match" and always keeps loading the results.

[image]

I am trying in it Chrome and IE-9.

**Update:**
The issue occurs only searching against "All Publications", searching against a particular publication works fine. 
Also, this is happening for all users.

Please help.

Comment: Normally when you get slow results I would suggest to look at your Database maintenance and make sure it is up to date (things like updating DB statistics, and rebuilding indexes). Not sure about the current Solr search in 2013, but I expect that requires regular maintenance too (check the documentation for Maintaining SDL Tridion.

Comment: ok.. I will do that. but the strange thing is, it's behaving normal for the other users.

Comment: If it is only your user, or maybe only your specific location (does your user work okay from somebody elses PC and does your user work okay on there), then I would probably look at your PC/network connection itself first. But maintenance can never harm and should be done anyways.

Comment: I suspect too, its location. I will update after maintenance.

Comment: Is it working correctly for other users for same version of Chrome and IE?

Answer (score 1):

Well, this was because of a `GUI Extension Button` in Ribbon.
Which was throwing a error in JS while selecting “Content Management” in the publications panel and freezing the search result window.

While debugging with FireFox FireBug, in the console the JS Error Tracked.

Actually, the custom button gets enabled/disabled based on the publication selected.
Now while selecting the “Content Management” in publications panel , the function `pages.prototype._isEnabled = function (selection)` in the associated JS was throwing error.

After proper handling of the error, the issue is resolved.